# Evaluate the double integral $\int_0^1\int_x^1 \frac{y^\lambda}{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx$ for $\lambda$>$0$.

Tags: integration

Evaluate:
$$\int_0^1\int_x^1 \frac{y^\lambda}{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx$$ for $\lambda$>$0$.

The solution is $\pi$/$4\lambda$. So I guess I have to use some kind of polar coordinates to solve the problem. But how would one deal with the bounds and the lambda?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 2):

First interchange the integrals and write it as $\int_0^{1}\int_o^{y} \frac 1 {x^{2}+y^{2}} dx y^{\lambda} dy$. For the inner integral make the substitution $x=y\tan\, \theta$. You will end up with $\frac {\pi} 4 \int_0^{1} y^{\lambda -1}dy=\frac {\pi}{4\lambda}$.

Answer (score 0):

First plot the given limits on the x-y axes. The required region will be a triangle consisting of vertices O(0,0), A(1,1), B(0,1).

Use $x = r cos\theta$ and $ y = r sin\theta$. So $dxdy = rdrd\theta$ and$x^2+y^2 = r^2$

At $y = x$, $ r sin\theta = r cos\theta$, $tan\theta = 1$ , $\theta = \pi/4$

At $y = 1$, $ r = 1/sin\theta$

At $x=0$, $r = 0$

Also, the upper limit of $\theta$ is $\pi/2$

So, $I = \int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/4}{\int^{1/sin\theta}_0{\frac{r^{\lambda}(sin\theta)^{\lambda}rdrd\theta}{r^2}}} = \int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/4}{\int^{1/sin\theta}_0{{r^{\lambda -1 }(sin\theta)^{\lambda}drd\theta}}} = \int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/4}{\frac{1}{\lambda}.\frac{(sin\theta)^{\lambda}}{(sin\theta)^{\lambda}}d\theta}= {\frac{1}{\lambda}\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/4}d\theta} = \frac{\pi}{4\lambda}  $